# Connecting Raspberry Pi 4 B to a HANNspree ht161hnb touch monitor

Tags: boot-issues

I'm trying to connect my Raspberry Pi 4B to a HANNspree ht161hnb touch monitor.
It's a first time use with a sd cart with NOOBS(I'm new to Raspberry Pi) It's booting up (I see a "For recovery mode press shift" screen) then immediately it goes to "No Signal". I tried both hdmi ports. I am powering the monitor with the original 12v adapter. I connected an USB cable back to the Pi. 
https://www.hannspree.eu/product/ht-161-hnb/
What can be the problem?

Comment: Welcome.  Any reason you are using NOOBS?  I would jump straight into Raspbian to save issues.  You could try the other hdmi port on the Pi.  How are you powering the monitor?  Does it have a USB connection back to the Pi?  Do you have a link to the manual if no one has one here?  You can edit your question to put these details in rather than using comments.

Comment: I’m now able to install Rasbian OS on my sd card while connected to my Hannspree. I can follow it on the screen, but after installation it returns to the same; No signal??!

Comment: Possibly it's the resolution or data coming back from the monitor baffling the Pi.  I would try adding `hdmi_ignore_cec=1` to /bot/config.txt and see if that helps. If not it's a case of going through https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md to set the monitor spec in config.txt

Comment: I added hdmi_ignore_cec=1 to config.txt, but this is not the solution. I'm thinking to connect the Pi to my working (not touch-test) monitor.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem with the same monitor and i use a raspberry pi 4, with my configuration works.
This is my config.txt file:

```
# For more options and information see
# http://rpf.io/configtxt
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details

# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
#hdmi_safe=1
hdmi_ignore_edid=0xa5000080

# uncomment this if your display has a black border of unused pixels visible
# and your display can output without overscan
#disable_overscan=0

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16

# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
# overscan.
#framebuffer_width=1280
#framebuffer_height=720

# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
hdmi_force_hotplug=1

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=86

# uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in
# DMT (computer monitor) modes
#hdmi_drive=2

# uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have interference, blanking, or
# no display
config_hdmi_boost=4

# uncomment for composite PAL
#sdtv_mode=2

#uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
#arm_freq=800

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
#dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
#dtparam=spi=on

# Uncomment this to enable infrared communication.
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir,gpio_pin=17
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir-tx,gpio_pin=18

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented /boot/overlays/README

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on

[pi4]
# Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver on top of the dispmanx display stack
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
max_framebuffers=2

[all]
#dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d

disable_splash=1
```

Comment: And what is different from the default settings of `/boot/config.txt`? Can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: I have tried with safe_mode unabled and the monitor work but at limited resolution.

Comment: I have tried with safe_mode enabled and the monitor work but at limited resolution. Reading the official guide https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md i have found the correct configuration using only some parameters enabled by safe_mode.